# Firma Electronica error: The available certificate selector didn't match any certificates

Tags: webservice, soap

Estoy enviando facturas electrónicas al `Webservice SOAP` de Pruebas (habilitación) de la `DIAN` y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
com.indra.mmdd.signature.exceptions.ValidateException: xades4j.providers.CannotSelectCertificateException: The available certificate selector didn't match any certificates
```

Quiero pensar que el problema esta en el Certificado Digital de pruebas que tengo, pero hace días compre un certificado valido ante la entidad ANDES SCD (aprobada por la ONAC) y continúa mencionandome el mismo error.

Alguien le a sucedido lo mismo y me pueda dar una retroalimentación?

Saludos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te sucede este mismo detalle al enviar facturas al webservice de la DIAN, es porque en las etiquetas **Cert** estas colocando el **subject** en un orden incorrecto, en mi caso, en PHP al extraer la información del certificado y obtenido el array de datos, dentro de "subject" los datos estaban por ejemplo ordenados de "A" a "Z", por lo cual, verificando otras facturas de ejemplo, los datos estaban colocados en un orden de "Z" a "A", por lo cual solamente después de extraer la info del certificado, la recorría al revés para escribirla en el XML a como lo pedía la entidad tributaria DIAN y listo, el error dejo de fastidiarme la vida :D

```
<?php
                    $certData=  file_get_contents("/url/mycertWithTags.pem");
                    $a= openssl_x509_parse($certData);

                    if( !is_array($a) )     $r= FALSE;
                    else {
                        $issuer='';
                        $subject='';
                        foreach( $a["issuer"] as $nodo=>$val ) {
                            if( $issuer )       $issuer= ','.$issuer; # delimitador 
                            $issuer= strtolower($nodo). '='. $val.$issuer;
                        }

                        foreach( $a["subject"] as $nodo=>$val ) {
                            if( $subject )      $subject= ','.$subject; # delimitador 
                            $subject= strtolower($nodo). '='. $val.$subject;
                        }
                    echo "<br><br>Subject:<br>". $subject;
                    echo "<br><br>Issuer:<br>". $issuer;
?>
```